# swift NSTimer userinfo

Tags: swift, nstimer, userinfo

I'm trying to pass a UIButton with a NSTimer's userinfo. I've read every post on stackoverflow on NSTimers. I'm getting very close but can't quite get there. This post has helped

> [Swift NSTimer retrieving userInfo as CGPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133228/swift-nstimer-retrieving-userinfo-as-cgpoint)

```
func timeToRun(ButonToEnable:UIButton) {
    var  tempButton = ButonToEnable
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("setRotateToFalse"), userInfo: ["theButton" :tempButton], repeats: false)    
}
```

the function the timer runs

```
func setRotateToFalse() {
    println(  timer.userInfo )// just see whats happening

    rotate = false
    let userInfo = timer.userInfo as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    var tempbutton:UIButton = (userInfo["theButton"] as UIButton)
    tempbutton.enabled = true
    timer.invalidate()    
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I realise you've managed to fix this but I thought I would give you a little more information about using `NSTimer`. The correct way to access the timer object and hence user info is to use it like below. When initialising the timer you can create it like this:

## Swift 2.x

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("setRotateToFalse:"), userInfo: ["theButton" :tempButton], repeats: false)
```

## Swift 3.x<

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector:#selector(ViewController.setRotateToFalse), userInfo: ["theButton" :tempButton], repeats: false)
```

Then the callback looks like this:

```
func setRotateToFalse(timer:NSTimer) {
    rotate = false
    let userInfo = timer.userInfo as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    var tempbutton:UIButton = (userInfo["theButton"] as UIButton)
    tempbutton.enabled = true
    timer.invalidate()    
}
```

Therefore you don't need to keep a reference to the timer and avoid often nasty global variables where possible. You may run into an issue in swift if your class doesn't inherit from `NSObject` where it says there is no callback defined but this can be easily fixed by adding `@objc` at the beginning of the function definition.

Comment: No problem. Could you mark an answer when you have a moment. Cheers

Comment: Additionally, you don't absolutely have to pass a dictionary as `userInfo`, you just need an object that conforms to an `AnyObject?`. Personally, I used it to pass a `String`

Answer (score 2):

macOS 10.12+ and iOS 10.0+ introduces a block based API of `Timer` which is a more convenient way

```
func timeToRun(buttonToEnable: UIButton) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:4, repeats: false) { timer in 
        buttonToEnable.enabled = true
    }    
}
```

A one shot timer will be invalidated automatically after it fires.

---

An similar convenient way for a one shot timer is using GCD (`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`)

```
func timeToRun(buttonToEnable: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4)) {
        buttonToEnable.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just going to post this as I read over it before I posted. I noticed that I had `timer.invalidate()` before userinfo so that's why it wasn't working. I will post it as it may help somebody else.

```
func setRotateToFalse(timer:NSTimer) {
    rotate = false
    timer.invalidate()
    let userInfo = timer.userInfo as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    var tempbutton:UIButton = (userInfo["theButton"] as UIButton)
    tempbutton.enabled = true
}
```